# Save PHP file_get_contents stream to AWS S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Im trying to get a remote file (an image) using PHP and then put that image to an S3 Bucket.

It mostly works, except that the file that is uploaded to S3 is empty when downloaded back again.

Here is my code so far:

```
$src = "http://images.neventum.com/2016/83/thumb100x100/56f3fb1b9dbd6-acluvaq_63324840.png";
$name = md5(uniqid());
$ext = pathinfo($src, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$file_content = file_get_contents($src);
$filename = "{$name}.{$ext}";
  try {
     $file = $this->s3->putObject([
       'Bucket' => getEnv('s3bucket'),
       'Key' => $filename,
       'Body' => $file_content,
       'ACL' => 'private'
     ]);
  } catch (S3Exception $e) {
    //Catch 
  }
```

Hope you can help. Thank you so much in advance.

**Update 1:**

The problem is not with the ACL (I have tested using "public"), is that the saved object on S3 is not uploded correctly (I think is something to do with the encoding, but have not been able to figure it out)

Comment: have you checked the $file_content is not NULL or FALSE? for file_get_contents() to work with http:// you need to set in php ini: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: Yes I have. And in fact, when I render the Image using $content_type to the client it displays properly. The problem is when that filestream is transfered to S3.

Comment: @PabloAdoue :: have you tried supplying the Content-Length?

Answer (score 0):

Once you upload image to S3 bucket it will be private you can't able to download directly. You need to give public read access to make object available for download to users.

Comment: The problem is not the ACL. It is uploaded to S3 as private because on the front end the SDK generates a signed link (based on permisions). The problem is that the uploaded file (on S3 console) is empty when downloaded. I have tryied to Use public-read as the ACL and that didn't change the outcome. The problem I think is the way I'm trying to upload the remote file content (file_get_content)

Comment: @PabloAdoue Then have to make sure image is visible before uploading to S3 bucket.

Comment: Image is visible before uploading. If I render the content to the client by setting the Content/type header to "image/png" and echo $file_content the image is rendered properly. Once I put $file_content on the S3Object Body is the problem.

Comment: @PabloAdoue While uploading image to S3 bucket, you have to mention S3 region endpoint.

Comment: It is defined inside the S3 object (as you can see, I did not create a new S3 class, I have it inside a container) and It works for streaming everything correctly. Is just images that Im having this issue.